# Ionic:unable to add image just above ionic tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.     How to add banner image just above tabs? I have tried to add image in index.html file its working fine but image display in all the pages which is not required.    Also i have tried to hide banner image from particular controller in `controller.js`.    Although it hides banner image but when i click on the page where previously banner displayed, it gets disappeared. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ion-nav-title for your each template not index.html

```
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>
      <img src="logo.svg">
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content>
      Some super content here!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.    I have two templates like `menu.html` and `home.html`.   In menu.html having  `<ion-tabs class=" tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light   ">` and home.html file  having  `ion-view` and `ion-content`  .   If i put image anywhere within home.html it always comes below the tabs section.   Also i have tried to put image within menu.html file but no luck it comes below the tabs.